# Removing all symbols from EXE file with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, obfuscation, strip

I'm linking an executable file with several static libraries (projects in my solution), and want to remove *all* internal function names from the final .exe file.

Which settings do I have to use for that, and do I have to do that in the library or executable project settings?

Simply building in Release mode doesn't strip the names out of the binary.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Project** -> **Properties** -> **Configuration properties** -> **Linker** and in the **Debugging** section set **Generate Debug Info** to "No".

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To answer a 3 years old question though, you should read it more carefully. This is about export names not debug information.

Answer (score -4):

Remove them using hex editor, they aren't used inside a code

Comment: Do you edit a photo in hex editor instead of Photoshop?