Is there possible to eliminate all mangled name strings in MSVC c++ binary without modifying the names in source code?
I wonder is there a way to remove or randomize the decorated name strings in binary compiled by MSVC without modifying names in source code? I found that if I run strings myexe.exe I can found those mangled names in the binary, it looks something like this .?AVClassName@Namespace@@

Build your application as a release build and try again

I've tried, those strings still there. I've used "/O2 /Ob3 /GL" flags.

You should go to project settings,  linker settings, debugging and ensure "/DEBUG" is not set. (Since you're using MSVC, I assume you also use visual studio?)

Related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814326/removing-all-symbols-from-exe-file-with-visual-studio

It's a Cmake project. I've used "cmake --build . --config Release" to compile the project. the flags I've mentioned are specified in CMakeLists.txt.

I've found that those mangled name strings also appears in utilities ships with Windows, like taskmgr.exe. if I run strings C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe | grep ".?AV" those familiar strings also appears in those binaries.

Depending on your needs, you might consider an executable packer/compressor (a program that compresses an executable, and adds a stub that uncompresses into memory before running).   That doesn't remove decorated name strings  (the strings will be recovered into memory when the executable is decompressed and started, so someone knowledgeable about the packer/compressor could also recover them) but compression does obfuscate them to a degree, which would limit ability to recover them with string myexe.exe

Yeah, I know that. I just wonder if there a way to do it with compiler or binary stripping tools so I can avoid to deal that on source code level. otherwise I might just use macro or something to do it on source code.

I wouldn't expect so.   The compiler writes the mangled symbols (as distinct from debugging information, which is optional) to object files because the linker uses them to do its job of linking (associating calls of a function with the start of the function, etc).  Linkers don't normally bother to remove that information - their purpose is producing a functional executable, not preventing attempts at (say) reverse-engineering.

Another source of these strings might be Run-time Type Information which you can turn off with /GR-

why would you care in the first place?

I've tried, everything still there.

@Gene I am trying find out if I can make the binary expose less information as possible.

@rstax -- why? what are you trying to achieve?

@Gene To harden the software, make RE harder. and I know. Its impossible to 100% make sure is not going to be cracked.

A hack I've used is to have a #define ClassName RandomSymbolA0721F2 in the global pch.h (Visual Studio precompiled header). This doesn't alter the main part of the source code, but the compiler and linker simply do not see ClassName anymore.
This only needs to be done for sensitive names. std::vector is harmless.

It turns out the solution is simpler than I expected! I wrote a script to replace those strings with \0, and my program seems to be functioning normally. Everything is working fine so far, but I’m not sure if there are any potential side effects.

The only potential side effect I can think of is if there are symbols that need to be resolved at loader time, such as a DLL that had a dependency on a symbol provided by the EXE.  Also might cripple typeid(x).name() RTTI groveling, which presumably the code doesn't do...?
